# How can I let android client connect to my Websocket

Tags: android, node.js, openssl, gateway

I'm working on project WebScoket that needs secure connection between server and client.
I want the client which is android device  can connect to my Websocket 
NB :can be multiple android device

---

##### Using NestJs as Back-end and webSocket

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  MessageBody,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  OnGatewayInit,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  WsResponse,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: '*',

    transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
  },
})
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  handleDisconnect(client: any) {
    this.logger.log(`Disconnected ${client.id}`);
  }
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('GatewayApp');

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.logger.log('Initiate Gateway');
  }
  handleConnection(client: Socket) {
    client.emit('connection', 'Success from server');
    this.logger.log(`connected ${client.id}`);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('events')
  handleEvent(@MessageBody() data: string): string {
    this.logger.log(data);
    return 'data recieved';
  }
}
```

---

main.ts where I imported files

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('certssl/CA/localhost/localhost.decrypted.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certssl/CA/localhost/localhost.crt'),
};
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    httpsOptions,
  });

  await app.listen(443);
}
bootstrap();
```

---

I tested https://localhost in https://hoppscotch.io/realtime I got succeed and every thing works fine 
But when I give my ip e.g 192.168.x.x to someone working on device android to access to my websocket he got failure to connect

---

##### My certificate generated by openSSL

[Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llePX.jpg)

---

The commands I used to generate my certificate files 

link : https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-get-ssl-https-for-localhost/

---

My questions are :

- Does the type of certificate can be the cause of the error
- Which way of ssl do I need : one-way ssl or two-way ssl
- How can I let the client connect to my websocket to get his ID

Comment: It's kind of unclear, what you need. One-way ssl means, client verifies the server identity - which is a common practice for secure communication but not authentication. if your server needs to verify client identity then it should be either mutual-ssl or 2-way, and client needs to send the certificates for his identity. It all depends on what you need to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for replying, my server doesn't need to verify the identity of client  , it will receive data from clients , How can I let the client connect to my server ?

Comment: My web socket servers are generally hosted on sub-domains so a wildcard SSL is required in my case. I appoint my DNS an "A" record point wss.example.com -> IP of server. The web socket server now just needs to be ran using the certificates.

Comment: If your server has a CA signed SSL certificate configured already, any client can connect to that server using the standard libraries of your stack. If your server has a self signed certitificate, probably you need to ignore the verification. Your question is likely to be closed, if you are not providing details like, the code you work on, technologies you use and what exactly is blocking for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time . I'm sorry for short description, I'm going to edit my post, to provide you more informations